# How to create random graph of n vertices with c fixed neighbours in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, graph-theory

I have written a code in MATLAB that allows me to generate a random graph of `n` vertices, each with `c` fixed neighbours without loops (note the edges are directed, thus "a connected to b" does not imply "b connected to a").

However, it is terribly inefficient, especially when I need to it work on magnitudes such as `n = 10000` and `c = 1000`. I was wondering if anyone could optimize it big time, or suggest anything constructive?

```
function [M]=matsrand(n,c)


MM=0;   %arbitrary starting value
while MM ~=n*c

    M = sparse(zeros(n));       
    ctin = zeros(1,n);  


    for i=1:n
        rp = randperm(n);   %generate vector of the randomly permuted order of n vertices
        rp(rp==i)=[];       %get rid of itself to avoid self connection

        noconnect=find(ctin(:)>=c); %generate list that i is not allowed to connect to
        where=ismember(rp,noconnect);   %returns 1 to the subset noconnect in rp
        noconnectind=find(where);

        rp(noconnectind(:))=[];         %remove the neurons i is not allowed to connect to

        if length(rp)<c
            break
        else
            r=rp(1:c);
        end
        M(i,r)=1;
        ctin(r)=ctin(r)+1;

    end
    MM=sum(ctin);
end
```

Comment: use the [profiler](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/profile.html) to find where you're doing the most computations and find out if you can reduce that. I think it'll be in the `find` calls...

Comment: you also repeat the inner loop over and over again, untill there is a lucky combination. Are you sure there is no way to avoid `length(rp)<c` by adding some checks somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll speed up things a bit:

```
function [M]=matsrand(n,c)

    MM=0;   %arbitrary starting value
    all_nums=1:n;

    while MM ~=n*c

        M = sparse([],[],[],n,n,n*c);
        ctin = zeros(1,n);

        for ii=1:n
            noconnect=ctin>=c;
            noconnect(ii)=true;

            rem_nums = all_nums(~noconnect); % remaining numbers
            rp=randperm(n-sum(noconnect));
            rp = rem_nums(rp); % remaining numbers, hussled

            if numel(rp)<c
                break
            else
                r=rp(1:c);
            end
            M(ii,r)=1;
            ctin(r)=ctin(r)+1;
        end
        MM=sum(ctin);
    end
end
```

If memory isn't an issue, I think you can replace the sparse matrix with an ordinary `zeros(n,n)`.

Main problem still is you have to hit that lucky combination.

Comment: Thanks! It did speed things up fairly well, except it is that lucky combination that's taking forever....

Comment: You should test this by running it a few times, I'm pretty sure it's faster, but because it's not deterministic (you have to keep on trying an unknown number of times) just testing it once or even 10 times, can give good results, just because you were lucky  10 times in a row (in theory of course)